# AS3: How do i create instances from base class in loop

Tags: actionscript-3

I would like to create some instances from a base class inside `for` loop.

I've created a MovieClip symbol and liked that through `Export for ActionScript`.

I'm trying to make some instances from that base class. The base class name is`Ball_Base`.

```
for (var counter:uint = 1; counter <= 10; i++) {
    var "ball_instance" + counter:Ball_Base = new Ball_Base();
}
```

It get below error :

```
Syntax error: expecting identifier before "ball_instance".
```

Please tell me what am i missing here.

Comment: Syntax absolutely incorrect. I can correct it but I don't know how you want to make use of `counter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is not right.

You must have a property in your instance about a name, for example

```
public class Ball_Base {
    private var _name:String;

    public function get name():String
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public function set name(value:String):void
    {
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

When you're in your loop, you do:

```
var myBall:Ball_Base = new Ball_Base();
myBall.name = "ball_instance" + counter;
```

Finally, if you need stored in memory all instances so, add them in ArrayCollection

```
var myArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
for (var counter:uint = 1; counter <= 10; i++) {
    var myBall:Ball_Base = new Ball_Base();
    myBall.name = "ball_instance" + counter;

    myArray.addItem(myBall);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding right above could should be:

```
for (var counter:uint = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
    var instanceOfClass:Ball_Base = new Ball_Base();
        instanceOfClass.someVar = "ball_instance" + counter; // Assign some name to existing var in class
    var varName:String = instanceOfClass.someVar; // save that name in var for further operation
}
```

Comment: Yes you understand fine , but i did not create base class manually. I create base class through `Export for ActionScript` option. How can i add some variables to base class as well ?